# Start an Activity based on the location

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to create an activity which will restrict the users to access the activity inside some location parameters. if they are outside then they cannot access the activity. The location parameter is big or large area, so access outside even upto 50Km is not an issue. but how to make it restrict inside the particular confinement?

Edit:
i am asking how to define the location restriction?, i am asking if the location is 100N and 100E, so how will i restrict, or can i restrict it using places name?

can anyone explain with some example or a bit of code!?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Dont start the activity if you are in a restricted area i would say. Its unclear what you ask.

Comment: i am asking how to define the location restriction?, i am asking if the location is 100N and 100E, so how will i restrict, or can i restrict it using places name?

Comment: Have you integrated the Location api?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `location restriction` ? It's all so vague. Do you mean `how to define the restricted area` ?

Comment: `i am asking if the location is 100N and 100E`. ??? Which location?

Comment: @Saadi my app is location aware

Comment: @greenapps i am asking that an activity 'activity A' i need only inside UK, so anyone outside UK will not be able to access the activity, and even if the app cannot get the location then also it cannot access 'activity A' .

Comment: Ok. But then i ask yet again: what is the problem exactly? I find it strange that you did not talk about a geofence yet.

Comment: i cannot figure out the code part! i know DUMB of me

Comment: If you would start telling what you exactly want than we could maybe help you with it. But at the moment we do not know what or how you want to code.

Answer (score 0):

if you integrated the location api, you can use this to calculate the distance between your particular location and the current location

```
Location currentLoc;

float radius = 50.0;
float distance = loc.distanceTo(PARTICULAR_LOCATION);
if (distance < radius) {
  //start activity
}
```

here the PARTICULAR_LOCATION is the location of the some area you mentiond

Answer (score 0):

In your onLocationChanged you can check if a user is inside a given location or not

```
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        float[] distance = new float[2];
        Location.distanceBetween( location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(),
                locationtomonitor.latitude, locationtomonitor.longitude, distance);

        /// distance in meters
        if( distance[0] > 1 ){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Outside, Distance in meters: " + locationtomonitor.getRadius(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inside, distance in meters : " + distance[0] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

if you want to check a specific country or city, you can use IP to location:

just send a simple get Request to **http://ip-api.com/json** url and you will get a json data containing info about country, city, zip code etc.

Comment: That is only to one point. And the restricted area is a circle. How to know that the location is inside UK?

Comment: Is your app using Internet? I may have a different easy solution for you

Comment: That is a nice service Saadi!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the **Distance** between the **Location of the Person** and the **Location with parameters** as

```
    Location personLocation =...; // Person's Location
    Location restrictedLocation =...; // Location with constraints

    // Calculate distance in meters to person's location from restricted location
    float distance = restrictedLocation.distanceTo(personLocation);
    float distanceInKms = distance / 1000;

    if (distanceInKms > 50) {
        // Place code for person outside restricted location's 50 KM radius
    } else {
        // Place code for person inside restricted location's 50 KM radius
    }
```